# Limit the amount of files produced by Drill when running CREATE TABLE statements?

Tags: apache-drill

Is it possible to limit the number of files use to create / represent a table when using apache drill's create table statement?

Currently have sets of parquet files stored in HDFS and am converting them to TSVs via drill CREATE TABLE, eg.

```sql
alter session set `store.format`='tsv';
create table dfs.ucera_internal.`/my/workspace/path/tablename/tsv` as 
select col1, col2, from_unixtime(extract_date/1000) as etl_date
from dfs.ucera_internal.`/my/workspace/path/tablename/parquet`;
```

The problem is that doing this process can turn ~12 parquet files into ~30 TSV files, which is causing other problems for downstream operations. Is there a way to limit how many files are used in the creation of this TSV-version of the table?

Could not find any such info in the docs (here https://drill.apache.org/docs/create-table-as-ctas/ or here https://drill.apache.org/docs/configuration-options-introduction/), though the PARTITION BY clause appears to come close (https://drill.apache.org/docs/partition-by-clause/#creating-a-partitioned-table-of-ngram-data) (but not all the tables have nice partitionable fields).

Comment: Had a similar problem with files imported via sqoop (wanted to control the number of records per imported parquet file sqooped in). This post helped with that: http://community.hortonworks.com/answers/67472/view.html. Basically using `--split-by` option to choose column that produces the most uniform frequency distribution of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adjusting the following config options [1]:

```
planner.slice_target
planner.width.max_per_node
planner.width.max_per_query
```

[1] https://drill.apache.org/docs/configuration-options-introduction/

Comment: Looking at the referenced docs, I am guessing that you mean that the `planner.slice_target` value determines not only when more threads are spun up to process, but also when a new file is created. So for a set of parquet files amounting to X records, should set `planner.slice_target`=X/Y in the *CREATE TABLE* drill query to guarantee only Y corresponding files are produced, correct?

Comment: Each output thread will create new file, the algorithm can be found here - https://github.com/apache/drill/blob/8edeb49873d1a1710cfe28e0b49364d07eb1aef4/exec/java-exec/src/main/java/org/apache/drill/exec/physical/impl/partitionsender/PartitionSenderRootExec.java#L122.